# Gaussian vectors formula

Tags: probability-theory

I'm interested in studying the minimal conditions over the gaussian random vector $(X,Y)$ which takes values in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ (where $X=(X_1, ..., X_n)$ ) to ensure that the following formula applies for any function $F \in \mathcal C^1_b$ (the set of bounded functions with bounded derivative).

$$ \mathbb E \left[Y F(X) \right] = \sum^n _{i=1} \mathbb E \left[Y X_i \right] E \left[ \partial_{x_i} F (X)\right] $$

For this, I start to define $ Z =(Z_1, ..., Z_n)$ a gaussian random vector independent from  $Y$, such that $X_i =  \alpha_i Y + Z_i $ $\forall i \in {1, ...,n}$ where $ \alpha_i = \mathbb E \left[Y X_i \right]$. Then we can write

\begin{align} \mathbb E \left[Y F(X) \right] &= \mathbb E \left[ \mathbb E \left[Y F(\alpha_1 Y + Z_1, ..., \alpha_n Y + Z_n) | (Z_1,...,Z_n) \right] \right] \\&=\mathbb E \left[ \int _{\mathbb R} y F(\alpha y  +Z) \mu_{Y|Z}(dy)\right] 
\\&=\mathbb E \left[ \int _{\mathbb R} y F(\alpha y  +Z) \mu_ Y(dy)\right] 
\end{align}

because we know  that $\mu_{Y|Z}$, the law of $Y$ conditional to $Z$, is a normal law and since $Z$ is independent from  $Y$.

At this point I believe that a integration by parts can permits to conclude and possibly make an additional assumption that $(X,Y)$ is centered, but I've been not well succeeded until now.

Also, it seems that it could help to show it for the following particular case by a straight forward approach. Then use this result just after the above conditioning step. However, it's even less clear to me how to conclude this way.

$$ \mathbb E \left[Y F(Y \mathbf1_n) \right] = \sum^n _{i=1} \mathbb  E \left[ \partial_{x_i} F (Y)\right] $$

Could someone help me please? Anny advice would be appreciate. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use that ( in standard gaussian notation)  $Y - \Sigma_{YX} \Sigma_{XX}^{-1} X$ is independent of X and hence $F(X)$ to say $ 0 = \mathbb E((Y - \Sigma_{YX} \Sigma_{XX}^{-1} X) F(X)$ and conclude that $\mathbb E(Y F(X) = \Sigma_{YX}  \mathbb E( \Sigma_{XX}^{-1} X) F(X) = \Sigma_{YX}  \mathbb E( \nabla  F(X)$

Comment: @mike: What do you mean exactly by $Sigma_{XX}$ and $Sigma_{YX}$?

Comment: covariance matrix of X, covariance between Y and X ... notations are pretty standard for joint gaussian ... wikipedia article uses $\Sigma_{11}, \Sigma_{12}$ for same

Comment: Of course is. It's never bad to check if are talking about the same thing. Thank's mike Another check, you suppose $(X,Y)$ a general gaussian vector, not a centered one, doesn't it ?

Comment: @mike: How do you justify the last equality? It's not clear to me.

Comment: i think it's integration by parts.  $\mathbb E(\nabla F(X)) = \int \nabla  F(x) e^{- \frac 12 x^t\Sigma^{-1}x} dx =\int   F(x) -\nabla e^{- \frac 12 x^t\Sigma^{-1}x} dx =  \int   F(x) \Sigma^{-1}x e^{- \frac 12 x^t\Sigma^{-1}x}$  where I've left out some normalizing constants that don't matter and the last is the chain rule